# Visual Studio keyboard generates wrong characters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard, key-bindings

Every now and then my keyboard in Visual Studio starts to behave wrongly.  For example Shift + 3 inserts a pound symbol instead of a hash #.  Shift + \ inserts a tilde ~ instead of a pipe |.  When this happens it only affects the current instance of VS - even if I have multiple VS windows open.  Only VS is affected - Notepad and other windows apps are fine.  Closing and then reopening the solution I was working on in a new VS 2008 instance resolves the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what key combination I have accidentally pressed to cause this?  And how to revert it?

Comment: What does it say in Tools/Options/Environment/International settings for the language?

Comment: English.  The only other option is "Same as Microsoft Windows".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had a similar problem (on Windows XP), where my keyboard settings would change without me knowing. @ would swap with “, # with /, etc. It turned out that there’s a built-in Windows keyboard shortcut to swap between keyboard layouts, and it’s ALT + Shift! I must have been accidentally pressing these together every so often.

I fixed the problem by going into the Control Panel, selecting 'Regional and Language Options', then moving to the Language tab and clicking the Details button. This shows you a list of all the alternative keyboard layouts that you have available. I just deleted all but the one I wanted, so that I no longer have an alternative layout to swap to.

Comment: +1. I use this feature all the time :D.
Changing the keyboard layout is per-application, which explains the OP's behaviour. I'd bet OP also has UK keyboard installed.

Comment: I use Alt + Shift fairly often to highlight multiple rows and columns for easy editing. Until now I've had no idea why weird chars would show up!

Comment: [Multi-caret selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text?view=vs-2019#multi-caret-selection) is exactly what kept causing me to run into this.  Plenty of ways to accidentally miss the third input in a `Shift` + `Alt` + `...` sequence.